# Switch fragments programmatically

Tags: android, fragment

I have a pager with two fragments, each with its own xml.
My question is whether it is possible to switch from one fragment to another programmatically and to fire on any listener?

Best Regards

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming you mean [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). You can toggle between them by using [pager.setCurrentItem(index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int%29)

Comment: ViewPager is within the same fragment.  He wants to know how to move between fragments.  I would like to know the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set current item in ViewPager and then you should notify the adapter to make it bring the new Fragment.

```
ViewPager ViewPager;
FragmentPagerAdapter adapter;

pager.setCurrentItem(2);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ViewPager`, you can try `setSelectedNavigationItem()`.  That is, you can switch from one fragment to another by calling:

```
int position = 0;  // position of the tab you want
((ParentActivity) getActivity()).getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
```

or, if you're using ActionBarSherlock:

```
int position = 0;  // position of the tab you want
((ParentActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
```