# How to change page with button in viewPager?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialog fragment that contains a viewpager with four fragments. The navigation between these fragments works fine with swipe, but I want to change fragments, with a button on the fragment.

I found that I have to use `setCurrentItem(int iten)`. But I don't know how to use in a different fragment, which contains the xml with the viewpager.

I have this:

```
class DialogFragmentContainer: DialogFragment() {

    lateinit var binding: DialogFragmentContainerBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DialogFragmentContainerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        if(dialog != null && dialog!!.window != null){
            dialog!!.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val viewPagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(this)
        val viewPager = binding.pager
        viewPager.adapter = viewPagerAdapter
    }
}
```

and the xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The adapter

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fragment: Fragment): FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 4
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when(position){
            0 -> Step1()
            1 -> Step2()
            2 -> Step3()
            3 -> Step4()
            else -> Step1()
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the fragment with the button, where I want to change to next fragment

```
class Step1(): Fragment() {

    lateinit var binding: Step1FragmentBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = Step1FragmentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        binding.btnNext.setOnClickListener{ 
            //I want to change fragment here 
        }

    }
}
```

Sorry, if it's too much code, and thanks!

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704429/switch-fragments-programmatically

Comment: I dont know how to call pager.setCurrentItem(int item) because i'm in another fragment wich have different xml file. The viewpager is the fragment container xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DialogFragmentContainer` is the parent fragment of the ViewPager page fragments; i.e. it's the parent of Step1 through Step4 fragments.

And therefore you can access it from `Step1` fragment, the fragment that you want to change the current ViewPager page using the `parentFragment` attribute:

```
binding.btnNext.setOnClickListener{ 
    //I want to change fragment here 
    (parentFragment as DialogFragmentContainer).binding.pager.currentItem = myItemPosition
}
```